# Python - Read CSV and output to strings

Tags: python, string, csv, converters

I'm pretty new to Python and I'd like to create a script that reads a UTF-8 CSV file containing two columns and writes the output into a UTF-8 strings file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

CSV Example:

```
KEY,LANGUAGE
keyname1,"Nononono “%{placeholder}”?"
keyname2,"Nononon %{placeholder} nononon."
keyname3,"Open in %{placeholder}?"
keyname4,GB
keyname5,TB
```

Desired output:

```
keyname1 = "Nononono “%{placeholder}”?",
keyname2 = "Nononon %{placeholder} nononon.",
keyname3 = "Open in %{placeholder}?",
keyname4 = GB,
keyname5 = TB
```

So far I was able to read the CSV file and output it to the stdout with the code below:

```
import csv

def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):

    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        print(line["KEY"]),
        print(line["LANGUAGE"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("data.csv") as f_obj:
        csv_dict_reader(f_obj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a good start with the `csv` module.

Now you just need to `open()` another file in "write" mode for output, and `write()` to it.

```
import csv

def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
    """Read a CSV file with 2 columns and output a new string. """
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    buf = ""
    for line in reader:
        buf += line["KEY"] + " = " + line["LANGUAGE"] + "\n"

    return buf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("test_trans_csv.csv") as f_obj:
        with open("test_trans_output.csv", "w") as f_output:
            txt = csv_dict_reader(f_obj)
            f_output.write(txt)
```

Comment: It works nice, but I still need to include the " " for the values. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you mean the "," (comma)? I can see the commas in your expected output, is that needed?

Comment: The commas are fine :-) It's the string that should be encased by quotes like in keyname1 = "Nononono “%{placeholder}”?",

Comment: Well you just add them:

`buf += line["KEY"] + ' = "' + line["LANGUAGE"] + '"\n'`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally figured how to add the values inside quotes and ; at the end of each line. 

 `"""Format KEY = "VALUE"; """
    for line in reader:
        buf += line["KEY"] + ' = "' + line["ENGLISH"] + '"'+';'+'\n'`

Answer (score 3):

Why bother with python for something so simple?

```
sed -e 1d -e 's/,/ = /' -e 's/$/,/' data.csv
```

Comment: Lol! Works like a charm!That's a hell of an one-liner! Thanks!

Comment: Hehe, I'm sure I could shorten it a bit more if there was any reason to bother :-). You're welcome, and please remember to "accept" my answer if it solved your problem (click on the big check mark).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
import csv
def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):

reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
for line in reader:
    print("%s = %s"%(line["KEY"],line["LANGUAGE"]))
if __name__ == "__main__":
with open("data.csv") as f_obj:
    csv_dict_reader(f_obj)
```

Comment: I tried changing the code but I've got an IndentationError: expected an indented block on line 4. Thanks for your help!